# Play .mp4 in WebView

Tags: android, webview, playback

Is it possible to play .mp4 videos in WebView? I cant use VideoView due to some application requirements. (I want the video in a frame)

Answer (score 0):

Android webkit is not powerful enough to support playing of video in webview or browser. trick is only that you have to call Videoview to play. Android native browser does the same.